# I get frequent warnings about missing variables in dependency list when using useEffect. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a React app and I get a lot of warnings about variables not being present in a dependency list in useEffect. 99% of the time these are variables that are used in the effect but should not trigger the effect to run again if they change.

In this example react complains about param, userInfo.currentcompany, showError and history missing from the dependency list. param and history come from react router and should never change. showError is a function that doesn't ever change but if it does change it shouldn't cause the effect to run again. userInfo is only changed in two places in the app and shouldn't change while this page is running but if it does change it shouldn't cause the effect to run again. And I use userInfo and showError everywhere in the app. Should I disable those warnings in this case?

```
    let {param}=useParams();
    
    let {userInfo,showError}=useContext(AppContext);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
    
    if(param===null||param===undefined){
    
    showError();
    
    }else if(userInfo.currentCompany===null||userInfo.currentCompany===undefined){
    
    history.replace('/');

}

},[]);
```

Comment: Just put them in the dependency list. "shouldn't change" and "never change" are statements that may not remain true very long

Comment: What if you really want to add a variable in an effect without making the effect run again if the variable changes?

Comment: Here's the thing. What you are seeing there are linter warnings meaning you've at some point decided that you want to follow a certain coding style either explicitly or because it's in a pre-set of recommendations (or it's your IDE's default). Broadly speaking I agree with that certain rule to be used, but in edge cases you can always just supress or ignore the linter warnings if you're absolutely sure that's what you want. They're there to ensure you are aware that you are doing it rather than doing it because you just forgot (which could lead to bugs)

Comment: I am using the default linter from create-react-app. That's why I am asking if I'm doing something wrong before disabling those warnings entirely.

Comment: If by disable entirely you mean for that specific case then you can do that since you know that you only want the effect to happen once. However it's good to not disable the warning entirely from all places since it's generally good to have some nagging reminder in case you omit the dependencies by accident somewhere else